# Как связать два списка из String.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

В фале ресурсов String.xml задал массив для Spinner.

```
<item name="one_m" type="string">1 минута</item>
<item name="five_m" type="string">5 минут</item>
<integer-array name="xmlStringsPeriodMenu">
    <item>@string/one_m</item>
    <item>@string/five_m</item>
</integer-array>
```

Теперь надо связать массив по ключу с другим массивом содержащий конкретные знaчения такого вида.

```
<item name="one_m" type="string">1m</item>
<item name="five_m" type="string">5m</item>
<integer-array name="xmlStringsPeriodValue">
    <item>@string/one_m</item>
    <item>@string/five_m</item>
</integer-array>
```

Сделать так нельзя т.к. поле name не должно повторяться. Подскажите как лучше выйти из ситуации? 
В коде программы явно задавать значения массива не хочется.

Comment: а в чем вообще суть, два языка хотите использовать?

Comment: Задача банальная, надо что бы при выборе пользователем "1 минута", переменной присваивалось значение 1m, для "5 минут" значение 5m и т.д пар много.

Comment: чисто гипотетически можно все сделать через слушатель выбора спиннера, или обязательно так нужно реализовать?

Comment: и переменная string или int?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как можно сделать все более просто на мой взгляд. У вас есть спиннер, назовем его например spin, дальше вам нужно забросить в слушатель выборе элемента спиннера такую штуку:

```
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //здесь вы вытаскиваете данные из выбранной позиции

    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

либо можно по-другому:

```
String Text = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

надеюсь один из способов поможет в решении вашей задачи. Удачи :)